# How to programmatically enable or disable Bluetooth Profiles in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

I have a requirement in which I have a list of paired devices connected via bluetooth to my phone. At some point, I have to disable/enable the sharing of media or contact details to my paired devices.
My requirement is to do this programmatically in android. 
I have searched this, but i could not find any solution for it.

Please let me know if it is possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just try enabling or disabling Bluetooth.

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    

            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
            }else {
                mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
            }
```

Comment: But i cant disable bluetooth completely.

Comment: In my case mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); works just fine to disable Bluetooth. can you show your code?

Comment: have you added permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"  android:required="false" />

Comment: With the code you have given, bluetooth can be disabled. But that is not my requirement. I have to disable the bluetooth profiles without disabling bluetooth. Hope you got me now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

**Get default bluetooth adapter**

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

**Enable**

```
 bluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

**Disable**

```
bluetoothAdapter.disable();
```

**Check Status**

```
bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code you have given. But that is not my requirement. I have to disable the bluetooth profiles such as media, contact details without disabling bluetooth.

Comment: No. I want to disable only the bluetooth profiles. Both bluetooth connection and paired devices need to be there.